# Little Endian Cabling?

Tags: endianness

I have a doubt about endian-ness concept.please don't refer me to wikipedia, i've already read it.

Endian-ness, Isn't it just the **2 ways** that the hardware cabling(between memory, and registers, through data bus) has been implemented in a system?

In my understanding, below picture is a little endian implementation(follow horizontal line from a memory address (e.g 4000) and then vertical line to reach to the low/high part of the register please)
As you see little memory addresses have been **physically connected** to low-part of 4-byte register. 
I think that it does not related at all to **READ and WRITE** instructions in any language(e.g. LDR in ARM).

1-byte memory address:

```
 - 4000 value:XX ------------------|
 - 4001 value:XX ---------------|  |
 - 4002 value:XX ------------|  |  |
 - 4003 value:XX ---------|  |  |  |
                          |  |  |  |
 general-purpose register:XX XX XX XX
```

Comment: You can't just copy the file path of your image;  you'll need to upload the file for us to see it.

Comment: If you've read the Wiki page, then you may have noticed that there aren't just two ways if you have more than 2 bytes. (I'm also ignoring bit endianness, which isn't discussed in the Wiki.)

Comment: I noticed that, too. if i have 4 bytes, and 4 places to put them, i can have 4*3*2*1 (4!) possibilities to allocate them in this places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. (I can't see your diagram, but I think I understand what you're asking). The way data lines are physically connected in the hardware can determine/control whether the representation in memory is treated as big or little endian. However, there is more to it than this; little endian is a means of *representation*, so for instance data stored on magnetic storage (in a file) might be coded using little endian representation or big endian representation and obviously at this level the hardware is not important.

Furthermore, some 8 bit microcontrollers can perform 16 bit operations, which are performed at the hardware level using two separate memory accesses. They can therefore use either little or big endian representation independent of bus design and ALU connection.

Comment: I can define my assembly instruction (e.g LDR which is 4-byte read) to be intelligent and reverse the bytes in order to read big-endian from a little-endian memory. but i think that by default LDR(load) does have nothing to do with little-endian or big-endian meaning that blindly puts byte values on data bus (the data bus can be little endian or big-endian) to arrive to register parts(low and high parts). also non-conformity with word-alignment(4bytes)addressing in read(ldr in ARM and right-rotation) has nothing to do with endian-ness.Am i right?

Comment: Sure, typically a "load into register" instruction such as LDR just copies bits from memory into a register via the bus, but then it's the way the register is hooked up to the ALU which determines the endianess. Bits are just bits; endianess doesn't matter (or even exist) unless you want to *do* something with them. And yes, word-alignment doesn't matter.

Comment: May i ask another question? in C or other languages there are different functions like printf() which performs READING from memory.is it correct to say that a **READING** from memory is the same as doing a **LDR** + definig the format to be used to read(interpret 101 as 1*4+0*2+1 or 1*0.5+0*0.25+1*0.125)?

Comment: my problem is this line of code (a=b):                               short a = 3; //short:2 bytes
int b = 65537;  //int :4 bytes
a = b; //for me it's the same as a READ from memory

Comment: I think "reading from memory" usually just means getting something out of memory. I don't think format/endianness really matters until you do something with the bits that you have read (in this case, you do conversion from int to short). Having said that, I think the definition depends on the context.

Comment: so when looking at a **memory word** to **READ it out** correctly I should know these things:#1-endian-ness #2-format(meaning multiply digits by which power of2)  but when looking at processor **Registers**,since the endian-ness has already been done, i just need to know the format in order to be able to read it out

Comment: The problem is that I don't really get what you're driving at, to be honest. This is getting to a philosophical level. You can read from memory addresses and get a collection of ordered bytes (themselves a collection of bits), and of course determining what numerical value those bits represent requires some additional knowledge (endian-ness and your "format", I suppose). The same is true of a register, except that the bytes are not individually addressable, so you don't have an ordered sequence of bytes but rather an ordered sequence of bits, which is why endian-ness doesn't generally apply.

Comment: However, bits are just bits. You can interpret them as a numerical value in a multitude of ways. I guess this is what you mean by "format". If by **READ it out** you mean find the represented numerical value, then you need to know the "format", yes. I guess you could say that endian-ness specifies how to order the bits from the bytes, and the "format" specifies how to interpret the bit values.

Comment: thanks for demystifying my phrases into the correct words. yes, I used **format** to say "the represented numerical value of these bits". Also i was referring variable datatype in C, C++. When i say '**int** a ; printf("**%d**",a)' (in c or c++), i think I ask the compiler to use integer representation(because of d) to interpret and show this sequence of bits!?